# StreamReader and Dispose

Tags: c#, dispose

I have a method, that takes Stream as parameter:

```
public void Method(Stream stream)
{
...
}
```

In this method I create StreamReader. Should I enclouse StreamReader usage in using statement? If so, stream will be disposed, that is incorrect. What is the best practise of using Stream and StreamReader in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope - in this case it's traditional for the caller to do the disposing.

Comment: Agreed - something along the lines of:
using (Stream stream) { Method(stream); }

Comment: Any examples of this?  I have this exact use case and would like some documentation to make sure the new `StreamReader` is being disposed in the method without any memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `Dispose` on the `StreamReader` will dispose the underlying `Stream`. If this is what you want then wrap the `StreamReader` in the `using` construct. Otherwise just construct the `StreamReader` and leave it for the garbage collector to clean up.

In other words, it depends on whether your function is 'taking ownership of' the `Stream`.

Comment: using statement calls .Dispose() at the end, so if you will wrap StreamReader in using(var reader = new StreamReader()) { ... }, .Dispose() will be called after the block, and underlying stream will be disposed anyway.

Comment: @Ravadre: That's what I'm saying. If you want the stream to be closed, wrap the StreamReader in the using construct. Otherwise don't.

Answer (score 2):

In such cases, I tend to write something like this and the end of method:

```
streamWriter.Flush(); // Only for writers, not for readers
streamWriter = null; // Show myself and other coders that lack of Dispose is not a mistake but it's intented
```

That approach is what I use for stream decorators that always dispose underlying streams, it's worth to mention, that in some cases (for example - `DeflateStream`) you need to call `.Dispose()`, but in such cases, stream decorators allows you to choose you want them to close underlying stream or not. It might look like this:

```
DeflateStream deflateStream = new DeflateStream(fileReader.BaseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
BinaryReader deflateReader = new BinaryReader(deflateStream);
var articleText = deflateReader.ReadString();
deflateReader = null;
deflateStream.Close();
deflateStream.Dispose();
deflateStream = null;
```

Comment: @AnsisMalins I assume you are refering to streamWriter in my example. not reader. It will call Dispose eventually, but it will call private Dispose and pass a flag Disposing == false. In this method, wrtier does NOT close underlying stream, which is what I wanted to achieve here (so basically - calling Dispose() on your own closes stream, letting finalizer do it - will not close stream). In .NET 4.5 (which was not existing when I wrote this post) you can specify if writer owns stream for Stream/Binary writer as far as I know, which was impossible at that time.